# Which C++ version has #include iostream.h already defined? "didn't have to use std::"

Tags: c++, versions

When I took my second programing class this was the version. (long time ago)
My teacher let me take it home to practice it was on 5-7 disk (3.5 floppy) to install.

I believe it's Turbo C++ Professional 2.0
It had templates, projects options and used the standard mini square blue screen (ide).
You didn't have to use any extra includes or statements for input, output.

With time that old PC went, taking the software with it. 
(yes I do have newer versions like builder 5,6)

If anyone knows the version please let me know Thanks ahead of Time.

Answer (score 1):

Borland C++ 3.1, too.
Visual C++ 6.0 and older.

Comment: Thanks Catalin Pitis I'll check those as well?

Answer (score 1):

iostream.h is the deprecated version.

use #include < iostream >

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces help avoiding name collisions. The current standard has `#include <iostream>` substituting the previous `#include <iostream.h>`. You should get used to the `std::` prefix to identify the namespace where the standard libraries live, or you can apply `using` directives to avoid having to write `std::` all around:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   cout << "No std:: required here" << endl;
}
```

The `using` directive tells the compiler to bring all identifiers from the namespace here, avoiding the need for qualification. Note that in the presence of ambiguities you will still need to fully qualify.

```
#include <iostream>
int cout;
int main() {
   using namespace std;
   ::cout = 5;
   std::cout << ::cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for your answer, while there are benefits to the newer versions. I believe it also waste a lot of resources and room in obj file. Programing law - Speed and Space

Comment: @Chubsdad: right, thanks. @Sam: What is your target environment? What is your development environment? It has to be quite restricted to prefer an old non-standards compliant compiler over anything newer.

Comment: Hey what version your using so I can do an accurate comparison?

Comment: I am currently using different compilers and environments... g++ 4.0, 4.4, 4.5 and intel 11.1 in linux, command line and with Eclipse CDT, g++4.5 in macosx command line and XCode, VS2008/2010 in windows both from the command line and IDE.

Comment: To start one of the biggest differences is the newer versions are more big project focused (that fine) and built heavily on class instances. Older versions while stringent (report errors for smallest things) is more object oriented (I prefer for smaller files). Not all the new standard aren't bad like having default pointer and user defined pointers.

Comment: You must be fortunate to work in the field? My self I code when I can? The same reason you use different environment is the same reason I use older versions, their are thing you like and dislike about each. I considered g++, I'm sure intel compiler is useful, I wanted to start learning linux since it's more programmer oriented OS. (from what I hear)

Comment: I'll continue my reasons for using older version in new topic. (C++ new and old)

Comment: @Sam: I am not sure I follow your reasoning, what are you referring to with 'built heavily on class instances' or 'more object oriented' and how they differ, or what default and user defined pointers are. I do recommend you to try linux (ubuntu is a rather easy distro to start with).

Answer (score 0):

`iostream.h` was a part of the standard library as documented by C++ Annotated Reference Manual (which was a de facto standard document prior to ISO standardization of the language).